# ChannelTrafficShapingHandler internals -- how does it work?

Tags: java, netty

I want to protect my server from DoS attacks by some rogue clients. I do not want clients to be sending a lot of data rapidly. To be precise, I want to rate limit these selected, potentially rogue clients. I am exploring using ChannelTrafficShapingHandler for this purpose. I have been experimenting with ChannelTrafficShapingHandler by monitoring server's heap and direct memory usage and also by monitoring iptables counters to see how many bytes are being put on network on both client and server sides. Clients sends a large amounts of data rapidly in these experiments.

What I inferred is that Netty limits the rate at which the data from the socket buffer is read on server. This slows down the client via TCP's flow control mechanism. Throttling is done at the TCP level. If this is indeed the case, I can use ChannelTrafficShapingHandler for my solution as my server's cpu and memory will be safe when malicious clients send a large amounts of data.

Is my inference correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it basically throttle how often and when reading from the socket is performed. So the back pressure is done via TCP